# Magic Index in Array with non-distinct numbers

Tags: arrays, algorithm

There is a task to find an index such that A[i] = i in a sorted array with non-distinct elements.

The solution given in CTCI is:

```
static int magicNonDistinct(int[] array, int start, int end) {
  if (end < start) return -1;
  int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;
  if (mid < 0 || mid >= array.length) return -1;

  int v = array[mid];
  if (v == mid) return mid;

  int leftEnd = Math.min(v, mid - 1);
  int leftRes = magicNonDistinct(array, start, leftEnd);
  if (leftRes != -1) return leftRes;

  int rightStart = Math.max(v, mid + 1);
  int rightRes = magicNonDistinct(array, rightStart, end);
  return rightRes;
}
```

Could you point me to a rationale for these indexes:

```
  int leftEnd = Math.min(v, mid - 1);
  int rightStart = Math.max(v, mid + 1);
```

In my implementation, which is the similar to above one, these indexes are calculated as:

```
  int leftEnd = (mid < v) ? mid - 1 : v;
  int rightStart = (mid < v) ? v : mid + 1;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those statements are equivalent. It is simply a matter of preference whether one chooses your implementation, or the one from CTCI. They are performing the same basic operation (I.E returning the max value/min value), and neither one is more or less efficient than the other. I would personally go with the CTCI implementation, simply because there is a good chance that Math.max or Math.min is better optimized by the JVM, but that is not necessary for a problem like this.